# Как преобразовать двойной указатель типа char к типу int?

Tags: массивы, c, c++

Как преобразовать двойной указатель типа `char` к типу `int`?
Имеется массив типа `char * *`. Его нужно преобразовать к `int * *`, чтобы производить арифметические операции над элементами массива. Как это сделать?
Пробовала преобразовать так:
`m[i]=(int ** ) rows [i];`
где `int ** m[10]; char ** rows`.

Comment: а в массиве char хранятся строковые представления чисел?

Comment: Видимо нет, так как девушка хочет производить с ними арифметические операции

Как правило указатель на указатель на char указывает на двумерный массив, если это так, то пожалуйста, укажите размерность этого двумерного массива какого типа элементы массива

Comment: З.Ы. звёздочку можно написать так: \\\*

Comment: Привел к более-менее читаемому виду, но я не сишник. Кто дружит с си- поправьте расположение двух звездочек, пожалуйста.

Comment: Такой вопрос, а зачем вам арифметические операции над указателями? Могу предположить, что вам нужны арифметические операции над элементами двумерного массива char. Конечно, я могу ошибаться :)

Comment: Еще одно (IMHO разумное (в отличие от шутки в моем "ответе")) предположение.

Есть массив строк с числами

   char a[] = {"10","20",30"};

Он передается в функцию, например 

   int sum (char **a, int n) { ...

Тогда просто делаете внутри функции массив целых, заполняете его преобразуя строки в целые числа и делаете свою арифметику

   int m[n], i, s; 
   for (s = i=0; i<n; i++) 
     s += (m[i] = atoi(a[i]));
   return s;

Похоже ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Дарьялла](/users/7513/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0), хотите подобное безобразие сотворить ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
  char **p[10];
  char *s = "xaxa";
  char *q = "oxoxo";
  int  x;

  p[5] = &s;
  puts(*p[5]);
  x = (int)p[5];        // это преобразуем адрес в целое
  x -= sizeof(void *);  // арифметика с целым
  p[5] = (char **)x;    // целое в массив адресов
  puts(*p[5]);
}

c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ gcc tc.c
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ ./a
xaxa
oxoxo
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $
```

Но лучше вместо int берите long, а то на 64-бит машинке проблемы могут быть.

Answer (score 0):

На c/c++ любой чар – **числовой** тип. Соответственно, проблема надумана, а любые операции над кодами символов можно выполнять прямо так. А вот если привести, то на самом деле будет нельзя, так как остальные инты имеют другие размеры.